Where can I find thermal conductivities of low carbon steels, i.e., AISI 1020 Steel in 8th edition of Perry chemical engineering handbook?
I need thermal conductivity data of carbon steel AISI 1020 for shell and tube heat exchanger design, but I cannot find it in Perry chemical engineering handbook, which is supposed to have all basic data of materials. The handbook has allowable stress values of nearly all steel alloys but not the thermal conductivity data for low carbon steels. So where can I find thermal conductivity data of all grades of steel in Perry chemical engineering handbook?

So what about other references? Perry is not the only one.

how about in a different book?

You might try Marks Handbook Of Mechanical Engineering, or a web search. in 5 seconds I got: 1020 steel also has a thermal conductivity of 360 BTU-in/(hr-ft2-F), a thermal expansion rate of 6.6110-6 in/(in°F) and a specific heat capacity of 0.116 BTU/(lb*F).
